# Persistent connections between WAMP and another server

Tags: php, wamp, persistent, connection

I have a web application mostly written in PHP and running on WAMP. This web application has connections to another server (not a database but a Java server) where it retrieves information from. There are lots of requests that will go on between the WAMP server and the Java server. Is there a way to reuse existing connections within each session? The other option is to open a connection and close it when the work is done.

Comment: Can you say what type of connections?

Comment: i found that persistent connections can be made in PHP using stream_socket_client() functions.

Answer (score 0):

I found that persistent connections can be made in PHP using stream_socket_client() functions. There is a good example on stackoverflow.